# JMeter Send 2 requests simultaneously, wait until all end with response, continue (loop) for 9 more times

Tags: loops, jmeter

I am struggling to send 2 requests to the same URL simultaneously and wait with the next iteration until all responses are received. I want also to loop such pattern like 10 times. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the way of sending 2 simultaneous requests using 1 thread (virtual user) - it's only possible using [Parallel Controller plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-sampling-for-jmeter)

Parallel Controller runs its children at exactly the same moment so it's sufficient to put the requests to be the children of the Controller and that would be it. More information: [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

The number of iterations can be set on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

[image]

JMeter automatically waits for the response after sending the request so Thread Group will proceed to the next iteration only when the last response will be received.

Comment: Well acutally I want to have 2 different users so no additional plugin should be required. But I have set up 10 loops, 2 threads and ramp up time to 0. First two requests are being sent at the same time, but every other is not..

Comment: If you have 2 different users to execute the same request at exactly the same moment - use [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer). Check out [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) article for more information